# Vuejs 3 and laravel : Component is missing template or render function

Tags: javascript, laravel, typescript, vuejs3, laravel-mix

This error occurs everytime i try to use vuejs3 with laravel

```
Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function. 
  at <App>
```

I started a new laravel project 8 with vuejs 3 and same problem again , i don't know how to handle it. Here's some of my configurations file.

### app.ts

```
require('./bootstrap');


import { createApp } from "vue";
import Welcome from "./components/Welcome.vue";

const app = createApp({
    components: {
        Welcome,
    },
}).mount("#app");
```

### webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');



 mix.ts("resources/js/app.ts", "public/js").vue({ version: 3 })
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        //
    ]);
```

### Welcome.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
  Hello {{ name }} welcome to my app.
  <hr />
    </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  
  setup() {
    const name = ref<string>("Bijaya");
    return {
      name,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

### package.json for versions

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.13",
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
        "typescript": "^4.4.3"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vue": "^3.2.13",
        "vue-loader": "^16.6.0"
    }
```

If you have any clue please tell me , thanks

Comment: Why are you importing welcome twice.

Comment: I did try some other way to import my component , i m editing the post .

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why but changing in app.ts this

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import Welcome from "./components/Welcome.vue";

const app = createApp({
    components: {
        Welcome,
    },
}).mount("#app");
```

to this:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import qrcode from './components/qrcode.vue'
createApp(qrcode).mount("#app")
```

did the work